# Have to reinstall adb usb drivers for every device, even when all the same hardware (Windows 10)

Tags: adb, windows, usb-drivers

**The Goal**
Get all adb devices (same hardware) to use the same usb drivers on Windows 10

**The Problem:**
Before an IT update, I installed the adb drivers once on my PC and every device was recognized in Device Manager (they are automotive infotainment units). After the IT update, the devices are shown under `Other devices` in Device Manager and I must reinstall the driver manually for every device Using `Update > pick from list > next > have disk > ... > android_winusb.inf`. This leads to a huge list of `Android ADB Interface` devices in Device Manager, but they are all the exact same hardware. I'm not sure what happened from that IT update, but IT department is unable to resolve.

**What I've Tried:** 
adding/installing/removing the driver with 
`pnputil.exe -a C:\path\to\driver.inf` 
`pnputil.exe /install C:\path\to\driver.inf` 
`pnputil.exe -d C:\path\to\driver.inf` 
with generous rebooting. I verified the drivers are in the system by looking at

```
>  ls C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\*android*
d-----     4/11/2023 4:41 PM  android_winusb.inf_amd64_e173223db663f87f
```

Also tried following [this tutorial](https://gsmusbdriver.com/install-usb-driver) to manually install the driver for legacy hardware. No dice so far. Greatly appreciate any advice, Thanks!